# TypeScript loop push

Tags: angularjs, typescript, bootstrap-grid

In loop session: I can get data out but outside the loop I can't "log" it.

```
getAbouts(){
  this.getInfos().subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.data = data;

    for (var k of this.data){
      // console.log("data is components: " + k.ten_demuc);
      this.getData.push(k.ten_demuc);
      //console.log(this.getData);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you specify what statements are those causing you troubles? Where are you expecting to "log" it?

Comment: I want "log" outside "for", but getData nothing

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Where is "this.getData" located?
At class level?

Comment: I'm done! Thank for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of var you can use let in the for loop.

for (let k of this.data){

}

Comment: I try "let" nor can